# monotonicity constraint question

Tags: r, neural-networks, quantile-regression

I used this model:

[quantile regression neural network](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qrnn/qrnn.pdf)

successfully in a couple of project. I am now faced with requiring monotonic decreasing rather than monotonic non-decreasing behaviour. Could I still use this model (e.g. by transforming the data somehow)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that multiplying the IVs with -1 does the trick (as it actually says in the doc after finally reading it thoroughly). Maybe this helps someone else.